# Couldn't find Timetable without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Generated a timetable scaffold. Then added a new action "clas" to my timetables_controller.rb.

timetables_controller.rb :

```
class TimetablesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_timetable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html

def clas
  @classtimetable = Timetable.all
end

private
def set_timetable
  @timetable = Timetable.find(params[:id])
end

def timetable_params
  params.require(:timetable).permit(:day, :clas)
end

end
```

clas.html.erb :

```
<% @classtimetable.each do |class_timetable| %>
  <%= class_timetable.day %>
  <%= class_timetable.clas %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_class_timetable_path(class_timetable) %>
<% end %>
```

Error :

> Couldn't find Timetable without an ID and the error is highlighted at, *@timetable = Timetable.find(params[:id])*

routes.rb :

```
resources :timetables do
collection do
  get 'clas'
end
end
```

rake routes | grep timetables :

[image: rake routes | grep timetables]

Comment: `def clas
  @classtimetable = Timetable.
end` You have forgot to write something?

Comment: I hope this is typo `@classtimetable = Timetable.`,

Comment: As per your routes, path should be `class_timetables_path`. How you got `edit_class_timetable_path` ? And `<%= link_to 'Edit', class_timetables_path(id: class_timetable.id) %>`

Comment: I see.. from where you got `edit_class_timetable_path`.. see the result is showing what I said you in comment. Your route path is wrong.